# Validation error with integer property (camel)

Tags: apache-camel

I'am using OSGi Configuration Properties in Blueprint Camel (v 2.13.2) and everything was fine until I tried to properties a integer property : timePeriodMillis in  tag.

This code works nice :

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf" xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">


    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="myprops"/>

    <camelContext  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="rt" trace="false" autoStartup="false">
            <from uri="amq://{{myQueue}}"/>
            <throttle timePeriodMillis="5">
                <constant>{{maxRPP}}</constant>
                <to uri="direct:mock" />
            </throttle>
        </route>    
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

When I properties timePeriodMillis :

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis="{{timePM}}">
```

I got two validation errors :

```
cvc-attribute.3: The value '{{timePM}}' of attribute 'timePeriodMillis' on element 'throttle' is not valid with respect to its type, 'long'.
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '{{timePM}}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
```

When I change it to (no quote) :

```
<throttle timePeriodMillis={{timePM}}>
```

I got again a validation error :

```
Open quote is expected for attribute "timePeriodMillis" associated with an  element type  "throttle".
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: does `5L` instead of `5` help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Camel documentation for using property placeholders. The section *Using property placeholders for any kind of attribute in the XML DSL* at [1] explains how to use placeholders for any kind of attribute. This allows to use string types `{{foo}}` for types that otherwise would require a number.

[1] - http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Thanks it works nice. I didn't catch the real sense of this section  cause the stop property is a boolean...

Comment: I'm having the same issue and while I looked at the link provided, it's unclear to me what to do to get it to "work".

Comment: Please check a detailed answer here --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125953/1521346