# Camel loadBalance failover maximumFailoverAttempts doesn't support properties

Tags: apache-camel

On JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 Apache Camel 2.15.1, when I have...

```
<loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false" id="load-balance">
<failover maximumFailoverAttempts="2">
    <exception>java.net.ConnectException</exception>
    <exception>org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException</exception>
</failover>
<to id="sender-service1" uri="cxf:bean:sender-service1-endpoint" />
<to id="sender-service2" uri="cxf:bean:sender-service2-endpoint" />
```

It works but when I try and use a parameter for maximumFailoverAttempts e.g.

```
<failover maximumFailoverAttempts="{{senderservice.maximumFailoverAttempts}}">
```

I get the error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '{{roamware.senderservice.maximumFailoverAttempts}}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.

If I try and use "Using property placeholders for any kind of attribute in the XML DSL" from http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html as described in [Validation error with integer property (camel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859466/validation-error-with-integer-property-camel) e.g.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"

    <failover prop:maximumFailoverAttempts="{{senderservice.maximumFailoverAttempts}}">
```

I then get the error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'prop:maximumFailoverAttempts' is not allowed to appear in element 'failover'.

We are using other Camel properties and the property is set in our configuration file. How can I use a parameter for the maximumFailoverAttempts attribute?

Comment: Use the Red Hat customer portal to get help with this

Comment: Have logged with RH also CASE 01644158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is not supported on the load balancers. I have logged a ticket to get this supported in a future Camel release: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10001