# dynamic timeout for camel split

Tags: timeout, apache-camel

I am using camel 2.13.2 and want to set timeout for camel:split that can be read from exchange.

static timeout works well.

```
<camel:split timeout="500">
```

but not the following. assume I have set property.timeout as an exchange property

```
<camel:split timeout="{{property.timeout}}">
```

I get following error during server startup

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 75; columnNumber: 67; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '{{property.timeout}}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.`

Is there anyway timeout for split can be set in dynamic way?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to specify this using the `prop` prefix which is documented in the Camel website. See the section *Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL* at: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

So that becomes

```
<camel:split prop:timeout="{{property.timeout}}">
```

And you need to remember to add `prop` in the top of the XML file as a namespace, eg

```
`xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"`
```

But see more details in that link.

Comment: Thank you Claus. This was helpful